# Ctags doesn't produce any tag when run on STL implementation

Tags: c++, vim, stl, ctags, tagbar

I am currently trying to understand the STL implementation of the Red-Black Tree which is located in `bits/stl_tree.h`. Since the size of the file is greater than what I'm used to, I found myself quite lost.

Since I used `Vim`, I installed `vim-tagbar` via the ArchLinux Repository.
I then runned `:TagbarToggle` while reading `bits/stl_tree.h` and found out
that there were only two tags:

```
_STL_TREE_H
_GLIBCXX_VISIBILITY(default)
```

I did the same for other STL file which gave the same output.

I thought it might have been `ctags` that parsed files with `.h` extension as `C` file which should not be the case therefore I runned:

```
$ ctags --language-force=c++ path/to/c++/implementation/bits/stl_tree.h
```

But still the same output.

EDIT: I tried everything above with both `Exuberant` and `Universal` `ctags`.
I also tried it with a C++ file which I wrote myself and the output was what it was supposed to be.

Does anybody knows the reason behind this?

Comment: What ctags are you running? You should get about 162 tags in total with a bare `$ ctags filename` and either [Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/) or [Universal Ctags](https://ctags.io/).

Comment: It's apparently `Exuberant Ctags` according to `$ man ctags`.
I did got the right output on a C++ file which I wrote myself.